# How do I mock a service that returns promise in AngularJS Jasmine unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I have `myService` that uses `myOtherService`, which makes a remote call, returning promise:

```
angular.module('app.myService', ['app.myOtherService'])
  .factory('myService', [
    myOtherService,
    function(myOtherService) {
      function makeRemoteCall() {
        return myOtherService.makeRemoteCallReturningPromise();
      }

      return {
        makeRemoteCall: makeRemoteCall
      };      
    }
  ])
```

To make a unit test for `myService` I need to mock `myOtherService`, such that its `makeRemoteCallReturningPromise` method returns a promise. This is how I do it:

```
describe('Testing remote call returning promise', function() {
  var myService;
  var myOtherServiceMock = {};

  beforeEach(module('app.myService'));

  // I have to inject mock when calling module(),
  // and module() should come before any inject()
  beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('myOtherService', myOtherServiceMock);
  }));

  // However, in order to properly construct my mock
  // I need $q, which can give me a promise
  beforeEach(inject(function(_myService_, $q){
    myService = _myService_;
    myOtherServiceMock = {
      makeRemoteCallReturningPromise: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve('Remote call result');

        return deferred.promise;
      }    
    };
  }

  // Here the value of myOtherServiceMock is not
  // updated, and it is still {}
  it('can do remote call', inject(function() {
    myService.makeRemoteCall() // Error: makeRemoteCall() is not defined on {}
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Success');
      });    
  }));
```

As you can see from the above, the definition of my mock depends on `$q`, which I have to load using `inject()`. Furthermore, injecting the mock should be happening in `module()`, which should be coming before `inject()`. However, the value for the mock is not updated once I change it.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is the error really on `myService.makeRemoteCall()`? If so, the problem is with `myService` not having the `makeRemoteCall`, not anything to do with your mocked `myOtherService`.

Comment: The error is on myService.makeRemoteCall(), because myService.myOtherService is just an empty object at this point (its value was never updated by angular)

Comment: You add the empty object to the ioc container, after that you change the reference myOtherServiceMock to point to a new object which you spy on. Whats in the ioc container wont reflect that, as the reference is changed.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I'm not sure why the way you did it doesn't work, but I usually do it with the `spyOn` function. Something like this:

```
describe('Testing remote call returning promise', function() {
  var myService;

  beforeEach(module('app.myService'));

  beforeEach(inject( function(_myService_, myOtherService, $q){
    myService = _myService_;
    spyOn(myOtherService, "makeRemoteCallReturningPromise").and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve('Remote call result');
        return deferred.promise;
    });
  }

  it('can do remote call', inject(function() {
    myService.makeRemoteCall()
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Success');
      });    
  }));
```

Also remember that you will need to make a `$digest` call for the `then` function to be called. See the **Testing** section of the [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

**------EDIT------**

After looking closer at what you're doing, I think I see the problem in your code. In the `beforeEach`, you're setting `myOtherServiceMock` to a whole new object. The `$provide` will never see this reference. You just need to update the existing reference:

```
beforeEach(inject( function(_myService_, $q){
    myService = _myService_;
    myOtherServiceMock.makeRemoteCallReturningPromise = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve('Remote call result');
        return deferred.promise;   
    };
  }
```

Comment: And you killed me yesterday by not showing up in results. Beautiful display of andCallFake(). Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `andCallFake` you can use `andReturnValue(deferred.promise)` (or `and.returnValue(deferred.promise)` in Jasmine 2.0+). You need to define `deferred` before you call `spyOn`, of course.

Comment: How would you call `$digest` in this case when you don't have access to the  scope?

Comment: @JimAho Typically you just inject `$rootScope` and call `$digest` on that.

Comment: @dnc253 Yes thanks! I just found that out on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. I totally had missed the integration of $q with the angular scoping mechanisms.

Comment: This is the approach I ended up with. However, I wrapped the construction of the promise in a helper function. It handles inject($q, $rootScope), $q.defer and then decorates the resulting promise with a "keep" method that calls resolve _and_ $rootScope.digest.

Comment: $digest is most commonly forgotten step.

Comment: Using deferred in this case is unnecessary. You can just use `$q.when()` http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @dnc253: I have an issue to get data from controller can you please look into it. Can you help me on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629138/how-to-test-and-resolve-controller-data-then-function-promise-and-get-orgin

Answer (score 70):

We can also write jasmine's implementation of returning promise directly by spy.

```
spyOn(myOtherService, "makeRemoteCallReturningPromise").andReturn($q.when({}));
```

For Jasmine 2:

```
spyOn(myOtherService, "makeRemoteCallReturningPromise").and.returnValue($q.when({}));
```

(copied from comments, thanks to ccnokes)

Comment: Note to people using Jasmine 2.0, .andReturn() has been replaced by .and.returnValue. So the above example would be: `spyOn(myOtherService, "makeRemoteCallReturningPromise").and.returnValue($q.when({}));` I just killed a half hour figuring that out.

Answer (score 14):

```
describe('testing a method() on a service', function () {    

    var mock, service

    function init(){
         return angular.mock.inject(function ($injector,, _serviceUnderTest_) {
                mock = $injector.get('service_that_is_being_mocked');;                    
                service = __serviceUnderTest_;
            });
    }

    beforeEach(module('yourApp'));
    beforeEach(init());

    it('that has a then', function () {
       //arrange                   
        var spy= spyOn(mock, 'actionBeingCalled').and.callFake(function () {
            return {
                then: function (callback) {
                    return callback({'foo' : "bar"});
                }
            };
        });

        //act                
        var result = service.actionUnderTest(); // does cleverness

        //assert 
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  
    });
});
```

Comment: This is how I have done it in the past.  Create a spy that returns a fake that mimics the "then"

Comment: Can you provide an example of the complete test you have. I have a similar problem of having a service that returns a promise, but with in it also makes a call which returns a promise !

Comment: Hi Rob, not sure why you would want to mock a call that a mock makes to another service surely you would want to test that when testing that function.  If the function calls you are mocking calls a service gets data then affects that data your mocked promise would return a fake affected data set, at least that's how I would do it.

Comment: I started down this path and it works great for simple scenarios. I even created a mock that simulates chaining and provides "keep"/"break" helpers to invoke the chain https://gist.github.com/marknadig/c3e8f2d3fff9d22da42b

In more complex scenarios, this falls down however. In my case, I had a service that would conditionally return items from a cache (w/ deferred) or make a request. So, it was creating it's own promise.

Comment: This post http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine_Provide_Spy/ describes the usage of fake "then" throughly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a stubbing library like sinon to mock your service. You can then return $q.when() as your promise. If your scope object's value comes from the promise result, you will need to call scope.$root.$digest().

```
var scope, controller, datacontextMock, customer;
  beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller,common, datacontext) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            var $q = common.$q;
            datacontextMock = sinon.stub(datacontext);
            customer = {id:1};
           datacontextMock.customer.returns($q.when(customer));

            controller = $controller('Index', { $scope: scope });

        })
    });


    it('customer id to be 1.', function () {


            scope.$root.$digest();
            expect(controller.customer.id).toBe(1);


    });
```

Comment: this is the missing piece, calling `$rootScope.$digest()` to get the promise to be resolved

Answer (score 2):

using `sinon` :

```
const mockAction = sinon.stub(MyService.prototype,'actionBeingCalled')
                     .returns(httpPromise(200));
```

Known that, `httpPromise` can be :

```
const httpPromise = (code) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  (code >= 200 && code <= 299) ? resolve({ code }) : reject({ code, error:true })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly.. you are going about this the wrong way by relying on inject to mock a service instead of module. Also, calling inject in a beforeEach is an anti-pattern as it makes mocking difficult on a per test basis.

Here is how I would do this...

```
module(function ($provide) {
  // By using a decorator we can access $q and stub our method with a promise.
  $provide.decorator('myOtherService', function ($delegate, $q) {

    $delegate.makeRemoteCallReturningPromise = function () {
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      dfd.resolve('some value');
      return dfd.promise;
    };
  });
});
```

Now when you inject your service it will have a properly mocked method for usage.

Comment: The whole point of a before each is that it is called before each test I don't know how you write your tests but personally I write multiple tests for a single function, therefore I would have a common base set up that would be called before each test.  Also you may want to look up the understood meaning of anti pattern as it associates to software engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I found that useful, stabbing service function as sinon.stub().returns($q.when({})):

```
this.myService = {
   myFunction: sinon.stub().returns( $q.when( {} ) )
};

this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
this.angularStubs = {
    myService: this.myService,
    $scope: this.scope
};
this.ctrl = $controller( require( 'app/bla/bla.controller' ), this.angularStubs );
```

controller:

```
this.someMethod = function(someObj) {
   myService.myFunction( someObj ).then( function() {
        someObj.loaded = 'bla-bla';
   }, function() {
        // failure
   } );   
};
```

and test

```
const obj = {
    field: 'value'
};
this.ctrl.someMethod( obj );

this.scope.$digest();

expect( this.myService.myFunction ).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect( obj.loaded ).toEqual( 'bla-bla' );
```

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet:

```
spyOn(myOtherService, "makeRemoteCallReturningPromise").and.callFake(function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve('Remote call result');
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Can be written in a more concise form:

```
spyOn(myOtherService, "makeRemoteCallReturningPromise").and.returnValue(function() {
    return $q.resolve('Remote call result');
});
```