# Unit-Testing a service in Controller with Jasmine in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

In my Controller I've defined the following service:

```
CrudService.getAllGroups().$promise.then(
    function (response) { $scope.groups = response; },
    function (error) { //error code.. }
);
```

Well, I want to test this service whether it gets a response or not. In test script at first I've defined a function to check whether the service is defined at all.

Test code:

```
describe('Ctrl: TestCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(module('testApp'));

    var scope,
        CrudService,
        ctrl,
        backend;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _CrudService_, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        ctrl = $controller('TestCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });

        CrudService = _CrudService_;

        backend = $httpBackend;     
    }));

    it('should defined the service getGroups', function () {
        expect(CrudService.getGroups).toBeDefined();
    });

    //this is wrong!
    it('should returns a successful response', function () {
        backend.expectGET('http://localhost:63831/api/group').respond(200, 'success');
        backend.flush();
    });
});
```

I don't know how to get a response in the test. I'm new in unit testing and need some help.

For a better comprehension here is the service code:

```
//CrudService file:
...
return {
         getAllGroups: function () {
             return ResService.group.query();
         }
}
...


//ResService file:
return {
         group: $resource(baseUrl + '/api/group/:Id', {
           Id: '@Id'
         }, {})
}
```

Do anyone has an idea?

Comment: `expect($scope.groups).toEqual('success')` seems obvious. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Pavlo How to define this? I guess the `expectGET()` is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you think so? The signature seems correct per [Angular API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), so are you unsure about URL?

Comment: @Pavlo I don't know, I thought that isn't correct. My intention is to see in the output of the test that te request was successful and the service gets the status 200

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect in the sense that it's not a unit test. If you are testing controller here, then you should mock `CrudService` and test that `$scope.groups` has been assigned correctly.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('CrudService', function () {
            return {
                getAllGroups: function () {
                    return {
                        $promise: null // return an actual promise here
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```js
it('should set groups', function () {
    expect($scope.groups).toEqual('success')
});
```

And you need a separate spec to test if `CrudService` calling backend correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How I have to define the mock there? Did you meant that I have to take this rows `backend.expectGET('http://localhost:63831/api/group').respond(200, 'success');
        backend.flush();` and take it in the comment of your code?

Comment: You have to return an object with a method `getAllGroups` that will return the something similar that `ResService.group.query()` returns (an object with `$promise` property).

Comment: thanks for your support but for me it is a bit difficult to define this because I'm new in unit testing and I still don't understand the concept of Unit-Testing the individual methods etc.

Comment: I've expanded the example a bit. For more check out [How do I mock a service that returns promise in Angularjs Jasmine unit test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705051/how-do-i-mock-a-service-that-returns-promise-in-angularjs-jasmine-unit-test).