# Unit-Testing a filter with Jasmine in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-filter

I don't know how to unit testing my filters. One of the examples are shown below:

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .filter('range', ['$log', function ($log) {
    return function (companylist, min, max) {
        max = parseInt(max, 10) || 100;
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(companylist, function (val) {
            if (val.maxSpread >= min && val.maxSpread <= max) {
                result.push(val);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
}]);
```

How you can see the filter iterates an array `companylist` and if the max value will changed the result returns a new list of company.

The company object is structured as follows:

```
{
  Id: 1,
  name: 'CompanyName',
  short: 'CN',
  maxSpread: 25
}
```

I have no idea to test this filter. Looking for a unit test at several tutorials and blogs but I've not found anything what could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject [$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter), and, use it to test your custom filter.

```
 describe('rage filter', function () {
  'use strict'; 

  var $filter;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('testApp');

    inject(function (_$filter_) {
      $filter = _$filter_;
    });
  });

  it('should return a collection with maxSpread in range', function () {
    // campanies.
    var companiesList = [
        // fill you collection....
    ];

    var myExpectedCampanies = [
        // fill your expected results....
    ];

    var result = $filter('range')(companiesList , 1, 100);
    expect(result).toEqual(myExpectedCampanies);
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to notice that the list returns from a database. Is this the same way to test the filter?

Comment: In a unit test you want to isolate what you are going to test, here, the question is if your filter in working as expected, so, no need to get the companylist from your database just provide a data test ...

Comment: many thanks for your support.. Do you have any idea for my last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694087/unit-testing-a-service-in-controller-with-jasmine-in-angularjs ... I'm looking for the whole day and cannot find any helpful example

Comment: Alternatively you can just inject the filter directly (change inject to _rangeFilter_) and then call it by name rangeFilter(companiesList, 1, 100). Not any better - just different syntax.

Comment: @ktharsis Can you help me in this thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694087/unit-testing-a-service-in-controller-with-jasmine-in-angularjs