# How to return mock json object from file as service response in Angular JS Jasmine Unit Test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, angularjs-service

I am referring the stackoverflow article [How do I mock a service that returns promise in Angularjs Jasmine unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705051/how-do-i-mock-a-service-that-returns-promise-in-angularjs-jasmine-unit-test). And found it useful in my scenario as well. But I want to load and return object from json file as mock instead of explicit object. So is it possible to achieve that?

I am referring below response:

```
describe('testing a method() on a service', function () {    

    var mock, service

    function init(){
         return angular.mock.inject(function ($injector,, _serviceUnderTest_) {
                mock = $injector.get('service_that_is_being_mocked');;                    
                service = __serviceUnderTest_;
            });
    }

    beforeEach(module('yourApp'));
    beforeEach(init());

    it('that has a then', function () {
       //arrange                   
        var spy= spyOn(mock, 'actionBeingCalled').and.callFake(function () {
            return {
                then: function (callback) {
                    return callback({'foo' : "bar"});
                }
            };
        });

        //act                
        var result = service.actionUnderTest(); // does cleverness

        //assert 
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  
    });
});
```