# Jasmine Spy : Getting an error in returnValue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test case with jasmine spy. Below is my service code.

```
function reset(someParam) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

svcTypes.getTasksWithRoles().then(function (types) {
    if (types.HadError) return;

    // do some stuff..               

    deferred.resolve(results);
}, function (errorResponse) {
    deferred.reject(errorResponse);
});
return deferred.promise; }
```

Below is my unit test case :

```
describe('tests for svcWorkordertypes', function () {

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('workorders.service'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('workordertypes.service'));


var svcWorkordertypes;
var svcTypes;
var $q, $httpBackend;
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_svcWorkordertypes_, _svcTypes_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_) {
    svcWorkordertypes = _svcWorkordertypes_;
    svcTypes = _svcTypes_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

}));

//This is working fine.
it('all controls should be set', function () {            
    expect(svcWorkordertypes).toBeDefined();
    expect(svcTypes).toBeDefined();
    expect($q).toBeDefined();
    expect($httpBackend).toBeDefined();

});

it('test reset method', function () {
    //Arrange
    var someParam = 'test';
    var types = [{ RoleList: 'newRoleList', isHeader: true, Roles: 'testRole' }];
    $httpBackend.when("GET", 'null/tasks/types?$select=IncludeRoles').respond(200, JSON.stringify(types));
    spyOn(svcTypes, 'getTasksWithRoles').and.returnValue(function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(JSON.stringify(types));
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    //Act
    var result = svcWorkordertypes.reset(selectedRoleName);


    //Assert
    result.then(function (res) {
        console.log(res + ' res output...');
        //expect(JSON.stringify(res)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(types));
    });
    //expect(svcTypes).toBeDefined();
}) });
```

Below is the error :

[image]

I have tried many ways with callFake as well. I found a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705051/how-do-i-mock-a-service-that-returns-promise-in-angularjs-jasmine-unit-test) but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

`getTasksWithRoles` should return a promise, and it is mocked to return a function that returns a promise.

It should be:

```
spyOn(svcTypes, 'getTasksWithRoles').and.returnValue(
  $q.resolve(JSON.stringify(types))
);
```

Comment: Thank you estus for the reply.  Now, I am not getting that error. However, it is still returning zero object in promise. Debugger is not entering into the "// do some stuff " code. First debugger go to the "svcTypes.getTasksWithRoles()" and after that directly go to the end of the statement i.e. return deferred.promise;.